# Does nginx worker Thread blocking while waiting for PHP?

Tags: nginx

It seems that nginx worker threads can handle other connections while waiting for data from the client or while the output buffer is full:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/inside-nginx-how-we-designed-for-performance-scale/

But do they handle other connections while waiting for PHP to generate the output?

Is there any further documentation how nginx works internally?

Comment: Well, for pretty much all network apps, each request/response pair represents its own thread (or forks a process instead of running a new thread within the existing process), so yes, multiple threads can be rendering output for their responses while other threads are in a differant state (perhaps recieving, perhaps sending a response, etc).

Comment: means the same thread which has requested PHP to produce output can do other connections meanwhile?

Comment: no, each new request creates a new thread (or forked process, which I believe is teh NginX approach) specifically for that request and its associated responsel, and will run them at the same time the previous response is being constructed. CPUs execute Threads of instructions, so a thread can only ever do exactly one thing at a time. Processes can consist of multiple threads working in parallel on differant CPUs/cores, but each thread is doing exactly one thing at a time. whenever things are done in parallel, there are either multiple threads or multiple processes (or both).

Comment: mh did you read about nginx? nginx main feature is to handle multiple requests with a single thread

Comment: no CPU in existance can do that. you are misunderstanding somthing.

Comment: ahh, I see, you are confusing Threads and Processes. They are not at all the same thing. A process can consist of multiple threads, or only a single one. In this case, with each request, NginX creates a new process (or pulls one from a pool of idle processes) and that process handles the request and its associated response. The previous process which is handling the prior request is still running while it does so.

Comment: Read the part of your link entitled "A Blocking State Machine". and note that the blocking is waiting for the client to make a second and subsequent request between the processing of each response.

Comment: nginx does not spawn processes, he uses a few threads, which handle other connections while they're blocking: https://www.nginx.com/blog/inside-nginx-how-we-designed-for-performance-scale/

Comment: "The blocking state machine" shows the old fashioned way, nginx does is as described in "NGINX is a True Grandmaster"

Comment: in you link, look at the second image. Its shows 4 NginX worker processes running seperately. The document describes this repeatedly.